# What to choose (in ASP.NET MVC) for a new webshop project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webshop

What to choose for the foundation of a new webshop project? I have narrowed down my options into using ASP.NET MVC, so that is a must. That leaves me with:

1. Rob Conery's Kona (not being updated anymore but all in all seems a good foundation, though with a huge amount of features)
2. MVC MusicStore by Jon Galloway (very simple, in fact it could be easier to start from scratch and take in consideration all the special details we need)
3. Start from scratch
4. Anything else?

I've worked with the MVC for the last year so I could start from scratch and have the basic functionality developed in no time but I like Rob's extended functionality he added.

It is just that I am unsure how difficult it is to tailor Kona to our individual needs - anyone tried it yet? For instance, use EF instead of NHibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, half the fun with Rob Conerys series was being "there" during the process he went through and the trials and tribulations he encountered. If you already have a foundation of using MVC for a year i'm not sure if there'd be too much more to take from it.

The most fundamental thing about the MVC pattern and the .NET tools that come into their own with using it (extension methods baby!), is that there are so many ways of solving the problem, some good, some better and occasionally some that make you go BAZINGA!.

If you have the time, i'd highly recommend just hacking away and see what you come up with.
After you've got a working prototype it's always good to then compare to what else is out there, for example with something like [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx)

Comment: Your second paragraph perfectly summarizes what I so adore about ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider using Rob's new starter site: ["Tekpub MVC 2.0 Starter Site"](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2010/04/19/tekpub-starter). It's inspired loosely on his experiences with Rails, and has a bunch of nice utilities built in from the get-go. It's built as a result of his MVC 2.0 course on TekPub, which he recorded with Steven Sanderson.